# Using an array of keys to push multiple s3 objects into 1 array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, loops, amazon-s3

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

function getAttachments(file, bucket) {
    var paramsArray = [];
    var attachmentArray = [];
    for (var a = 0; a < file.length; a++) {
        paramsArray.push({
            Bucket: bucket,
            Key: file[a]
        });
    }
    paramsArray.map(x = > s3.getObject(x, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        attachmentArray.push({
            filename: x.Key,
            content: data.Body
        });
        console.log(attachmentArray)
    })
)
}

var attachments = ['a.doc', 'b.doc', 'c.doc', 'd.doc', 'e.doc']

getAttachments(attachments, 
'exampleBucket')
```

I want to log a single array of objects, each with the key as a filename and a buffer string as the content. However, in this example I am logging multiple arrays increasing in size for each element in the attachments array.

These are in the correct format for example: `[{filename: a.doc, content: 'Buffer String'}]`, but I only want one array with the 5 objects returned in that format.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Can you show an example of what you get now?

Comment: Your code is messy... Why do you create the variable `attachmentsToSend`? It's unnecessary.

Comment: it is something like this = [{filename: 'a.doc', bufferString}], [{filename: a.doc, content: bufferString}, {filename: 'b.doc', content: bufferString}], [{filename: a.doc, content: bufferString}, {filename: 'b.doc', content: bufferString}, {filename: 'c.doc', content: bufferString}]  and so on.

Comment: Sorry, I quickly adapted it from something else so I could ask the question here, I am not so experienced yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here are he list of the file names I am trying to download from ascendon1 bucket

here is the AJAX request

```
var data = {fileNames: ['1.txt','2.txt']};
      $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'downloadFiles',
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    processData: false,
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    success:function(data){
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });
```

Here is the NodeJS Code

```
 app.post('/downloadFiles',function(req,res){

        var promises =[];
        var filesContent = [];
        var filesToDownload = req.body.fileNames
        for(var z=0; z<req.body.fileNames.length;z++){
            var fileName = filesToDownload[z];
            promises.push(getAttachment(fileName));
        }

        Promise.all(promises).then(function(data){
            for(var z=0; z<req.body.fileNames.length;z++){
                var contents={
                    filename: filesToDownload[z],
                    content: data[z].Body
                };
                filesContent.push(contents);
            }
            console.log(filesContent);

        }).catch(function(error){
            console.log(error.stack);
        })

    })

    function getAttachment(fileName){
        var params ={
            Bucket: "ascendon1", 
            Key: fileName
        }
        return s3.getObject(params).promise();
    }
```

here is the final output, we got the all the contents that we requested in a single array i.e is filesContent

[image: output]

Comment: This also totally works, and didn't really have to modify it at all, thank you! I really should have used promises, will look into them more!

Answer (score 0):

Just change your code to this one:

```js
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const attachments = ['a.doc', 'b.doc', 'c.doc', 'd.doc', 'e.doc']

getAttachments(attachments, bucket)
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);

function getAttachments(files, bucket) {
  return files.map(filename => getAttachment(filename, bucket));
}

function getAttachment(filename, bucket){
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    const params = {
            Bucket: bucket,
            Key: filename
        };
    s3.getObject(params, (error, data) => {
      if(error) return reject(error);
      return resolve({
        filename: filename,
        content: data.Body
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Or you can drop a `getAttachments` function at all.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you this really helped. I should have used promises to begin with but need to read up on them more! Had to modify it ever so so slightly but almost works as is, thanks!